# Unzip Folders to Parent Directory Keeping Zipped Folder Name

Tags: bash, zip, unzip

I have a file structure as follows:

- archives/

  - zips/

    - zipfolder1.zip
    - zipfolder2.zip
    - zipfolder3.zip
      ...
    - zipfolderN.zip

I have a script that unzips the folders to the parent directory "archives", but it is unzipping the contents of the folders to the "archives" directory. I need the zipped folders to remain as folders under the "archives" directory. The resultant file structure should look like this:

- archives/

  - zips/

    - zipfolder1.zip
    - zipfolder2.zip
      ...
  - zipfolder1/

    - contents...
  - zipfolder2/

    - contents...
  - ...

I am currently using the following:

```
find /home/username/archives/zips/*.zip -type f | xargs -i unzip -d ../ -q '{}'
```

How can I modify this line to keep the original folder names? Is it as simple as using `../*`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `basename` to extract the zip into the desired directory:

```
find /home/username/archives/zips/*.zip -type f -exec sh -c 'unzip -q -d ../"$(basename "{}" .zip)" "{}"' \;
```

Comment: The terminal opens a second line and awaits input when I use `unzip -q -d ../"$(basename "{}" .zip)" "{}"' \;` I understand what the `basename` part is doing, but can only get it to work without the `' \;` removed. This gives me the path `..//home/username/archives/zips/zipfolder1.zip` not `../zipfolder1`. It appears that the `basename` is working alone but not enclosed in the $().

Comment: @Matt it seems that there was a typo.  could you try the edit above?

Comment: That is working. I am going to use `-execdir` instead of `-exec` because the script is not run from the "zips" directory and `../` may be interpreted wrong.

Comment: Actually, that worked separately but in the script it doesn't remove the .zip from the basename. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: If anyone encounters this issue also, [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/coreutils/+bug/523453) explains it nicely. Basically `basename '{}' .zip` is run separately and returns `{}`. Thus the command becomes `unzip -q -d ../'{}' '{}'`, hence the wrong path.